# html5 canvas: clipping by color

Tags: html, canvas, pixel, clip

is there any way to choose an area on the canvas by color and clip it?
I want to be able to clip an undefined aread that the only thing in common between all the pixels is that they all have the same color.
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `clip` it?

Answer (score 4):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/RSeFD/2/)**

Below is a way to select a color.. and do whatever you want with it. I pass a color I want to find iterate over *every* pixel and remove the color that matches, since Im not sure what you meant by clipping I assumed you mean remove. However please note on large images this method will be slow.

```
// Takes an array with 3 color components, rgb     
function removeColor(color){
    var canvasData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 256, 256),
        pix = canvasData.data;

    for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i <n; i += 4) {
        if(pix[i] === color[0] && pix[i+1] === color[1] && pix[i+2] === color[2]){
             pix[i+3] = 0;   
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(canvasData, 0, 0);
}

removeColor([0,0,255]); // Removes blue.
```

And like Simon pointed out the code above will get the *exact* color. Below will grab the approximate color, which is good if you have colors overlapping or very close to each other.

**[Demo 2 with approximation](http://jsfiddle.net/CqTEV/9/)**

Comment: Unless the image in question is pixel-perfect, it might be worth approximating your conditionals, even by a large amount: http://jsfiddle.net/CqTEV/9/

Comment: @SimonSarris yeah I considered that as well, I noticed the edges werent selected in mine due to color bleed and throwing off the exact values. Ill add your js fiddle to the answer and give you credit.